# How can one bind datetime2(SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP) using SQLBindParameter?

Tags: database, odbc, datetime2

I am trying to bind datetime2 parameter using SQLBindParameter for `SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP` data type as below

`SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 7, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 0, 0, &datetime2, 0, NULL);`

also tried this:

`rc = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 8, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TIMESTAMP_LEN + 1, 7, &rec.datetime2, 0, NULL);`

rc is 0

when I exceute the query (INSERT)
`SQLExecDirect(hStmt, const_cast<wchar_t*>(query.c_str()), SQL_NTS);`
I get 22008 sqlstate error indicating Datetime field overflow;

I've looked for any sample code on this data type and couldn't find any working example, is there a ninja out there who has a solution for this type?
it is fine for SQL_TYPE_TIME with precision 7.

Comment: I first thought that there is a special extension for Datetime2 (like there is for time2), but there is none - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677267.aspx

Can you show the values you are populating into the `SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT` that is being bound as input parameter?

Comment: @erg sure, this is the value    `SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT datetime2;
        datetime2.year = 1999;
        datetime2.month = 2;
        datetime2.day = 3;
        datetime2.hour = 8;
        datetime2.minute = 20;
        datetime2.second = 30;
        datetime2.fraction = 123;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same error in SQL Server 2014: If I bind using `nResult = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TIMESTAMP, 0, 0, &ts, sizeof(ts), &cbValue);`
, I get:

> ERROR; native: 0; state: 22008; msg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for 
>   SQLerver]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds
>   the scale specified in the parameter binding.

So, I tried to examine what the server actually expects, with code like this:

```
nResult = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR*)L"INSERT INTO tTestTable (myTestCol, d2) VALUES(100, ?)", SQL_NTS);

SQLSMALLINT   DataType, DecimalDigits, Nullable;
SQLUINTEGER   ParamSize;

nResult = SQLDescribeParam(hstmt, 1, &DataType, &ParamSize, &DecimalDigits, &Nullable);
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
{
    printErrStmt(hstmt);
}
std::wcout << L"ParamSize: " << ParamSize << L"; DecimalDigits: " << DecimalDigits << std::endl;
```

This prints out:

> ParamSize: 27; DecimalDigits: 7

So, lets try with 27 and 7 and a fraction of `123` - and I still get the error:

> ERROR; native: 0; state: 22008; msg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for
>   SQL erver]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds
>   the scale specified in the parameter binding.

But then I found the sample here at microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff878122%28v=sql.120%29.aspx 
This sample makes things even more confusing, as they do exactly the same thing? Wait - the difference is, they use a fraction value of only `100` - can that make a difference? Yes, it does. Changing the fraction to `100` makes things work. Why?

Lets look at SQL Server 2014 directly. If I inserted a Row (from ODBC) with a fraction of `100` this gets displayed (in SQL Server Management Studio) as: `1999-02-03 08:20:30.0000001`. Remember what the fraction is exactly: From the docs at MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> [b]   The value of the fraction field is the number of billionths of a
>   second and ranges from 0 through 999,999,999 (1 less than 1 billion).
>   For example, the value of the fraction field for a half-second is
>   500,000,000, for a thousandth of a second (one millisecond) is
>   1,000,000, for a millionth of a second (one microsecond) is 1,000, and
>   for a billionth of a second (one nanosecond) is 1.

So: A fraction of `100` would be 100 billionths of a second, this is `000,000,100`. But the Datetime2 field has a precision of `7`. As the last part is `00` there are no rounding errors. But if you pass in `123` this would be `000,000,123`. This cannot be stored in a datetime with a precision of `7.`. If we change the `123`to `12300`, the thing can be stored: It matches up to `000,012,300`, this fits into the datetime with a precision of 7, and SQL Server finally displays: `1999-02-03 08:20:30.0000123`.

I hope this helps, and I hope I understood and explained the fraction-thing right.

Comment: This is strange, I'm getting 23 as param size and 3 as decimal digits. Could this also possibly be driver related?

Comment: @Vinzenz: For a datetime2 field?

Comment: No it's a stored procedure parameter of type `DATETIME`. The driver is `Native Client 11` and I did the describe param the way you did it. I've researched a bit and it seems that the param size can actually vary but is usually 27, 16 or 23. With the decimal digits, I don't know.

Comment: @Vinzenz: This is expected behavior, a `Datatime` field has a parameter size of 23 and a fixed precision of 3, while a `Datetime2` has a parameter size of 27 and the precision may vary, depending on the field definition.