# ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding. SqlState22008

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, odbc, odbc-sql-server-driver, sql-server-azure

I'm trying to insert TimeStamp Value into AzureSQL Server's DB table using ODBC driver 18 and I have set ODBC version as 3.0(SQL_OV_ODBC3). However I am getting below error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding. SqlState = 22008

I write a sample code just to figured out that it also failed with same error. Below is the sample code

```
    std::string sQuery("insert into DB_TEST.backlog_period (periodid, starttime)  values (?, ?)");
    SQLHSTMT hstmt = SQL_NULL_HSTMT;    // Statement handle
    SQLRETURN retcode;          // Return status
    WCHAR* wsQuery = string_to_whar(sQuery);
    // Allocate Statement Handle
    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, m_hdbc, &hstmt);
    if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error";
        return;
    }
    SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT* pOid = new SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT;
    SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT* m_pTimeStamp = new SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT;
    size_t nPos = 0;
    SYSTEMTIME Time;
    GetSystemTime(&Time);
    ConvertDoubleToNumericStruct(9999, *pOid);
    
    m_pTimeStamp.year = Time.wYear;
    m_pTimeStamp.month = Time.wMonth;
    m_pTimeStamp.day = Time.wDay;
    m_pTimeStamp.hour = Time.wHour;
    m_pTimeStamp.minute = Time.wMinute;
    m_pTimeStamp.second = Time.wSecond;
    m_pTimeStamp.fraction = Time.wMilliseconds;
    
    SQLWCHAR ColumnName[MAX_COL_NAME_LEN];
    SQLSMALLINT    ColumnNameLen;
    SQLSMALLINT    ColumnDataType;
    SQLULEN        ColumnDataSize;
    SQLSMALLINT    ColumnDataDigits;
    SQLSMALLINT    ColumnDataNullable;
    retcode = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR*)wsQuery, SQL_NTSL);

    SQLSMALLINT NumParams;
    SQLNumParams(hstmt, &NumParams);

    retcode = SQLDescribeParam(hstmt,  1, &ColumnDataType, &ColumnDataSize, &ColumnDataDigits, &ColumnDataNullable);
    checkAndThrowError(retcode, hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_NUMERIC, SQL_NUMERIC, ColumnDataSize, ColumnDataDigits, pOid, sizeof(SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT), 0);
    //above call is equivalent to     
    //SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_NUMERIC, SQL_NUMERIC, 10, 0, pOid, sizeof(SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT), 0);
    checkAndThrowError(retcode, hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
    
retcode = SQLDescribeParam(hstmt, 2, &ColumnDataType, &ColumnDataSize, &ColumnDataDigits, &ColumnDataNullable);
    checkAndThrowError(retcode, hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TIMESTAMP, ColumnDataSize, ColumnDataDigits, m_pTimeStamp, sizeof(SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT), 0);
        //above call is equivalent to     
    //SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TIMESTAMP, 22, 2, m_pTimeStamp, sizeof(SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT), 0);
    checkAndThrowError(retcode, hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    retcode = SQLExecute(hstmt); // This is getting failed
    checkAndThrowError(retcode, hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
```

This sample code is also geeting failed with same error.
I am also attaching the table description [image: Table Description]

I have seen similar problem and solution on stackoverflow but nothing works for me.
I'm using Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

**I'll be greatfull If any one can help. Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: If you're using Azure SQL database, why have you also tagged the completely unsupported (for **4 years**) SQL Server 2008? Are you *really* also using that version?

Comment: Well, you have a `datetime2(2)` data type so the allowable range of fractional seconds values is `0`..`99`. What's the value of `Time.wMilliseconds` when you get the error?

Comment: I have tried hardcoded it to 0 as well but issue persist in that case as well. In actual code as well fraction part it always 0. I'll double check.

Comment: @ThomA that was by mistake

Comment: If you're using ODBC 3.0 should you be using `SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP` for `datetime2` parameters instead of ODBC 2.0's `SQL_TIMESTAMP`? Ref: [Data Type Mapping in Parameters and Resultsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-date-time/data-type-support-for-odbc-date-and-time-improvements?view=sql-server-ver16#data-type-mapping-in-parameters-and-resultsets)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks. Code works only if I provide fraction values to 0. It failes for every other values.
I also tried to look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578536/how-can-one-bind-datetime2sql-c-type-timestamp-using-sqlbindparameter but can't get anything.